# How to avoid horizontal mouse scrolling for tab panel overflow?

Tags: javascript, extjs, scroll, extjs5, tabpanel

I need to disable mouse scroll horizontal scrolling while hovering tab panel title text.

If you `hover tab title and try mouse scroll`, it start scrolling horizontal way.Its OK for tapping left and right navigation arrow to scroll.
How can avoid this horizontal scrolling which is happening my mouse scroll ?
Please find fiddle for same.

**Note** - Look like this scrolling happen with Google chrome browser only.

[ExtJS Tab panel Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1a41)

Comment: Set `Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.Scroller.prototype.wheelIncrement = 0;`.

Comment: It's working.Thanks.where should I add this code line so this thing will go specific to single tab panel only instead of general one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Evan said, set the wheelIncrement to 0. If you want to add that to a specific panel, add it with a listener:

```
listeners: {
    boxready: function(panel) {
        var layout = panel.tabBar.getLayout();

        layout.overflowHandler.wheelIncrement = 0;
    }
}
```